# Styling lists in org-export (html)

Tags: org-mode, org-export

So, for variety's sake I'd like lists and sublists to have different styles.  In emacs, I've enabled `org-list-allow-alphabetical`, but this doesn't work with export ([not a bug](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#sec-11-5)).  However, there doesn't seem to be any simple way to change styles without adding extensive latex or html code to the file.

For example, with a list like this,

```
1. Parent
   1. child
```

I'd like to use a different marker for the sublist, to avoid confusion,  eg

```
1. Parent
   a) child
```

Latex seems to do this rather well by default.  Is there a way to specify it for other exporters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `html` output from the exporter is just nested `ol` lists without any labels.  To alter the labels you can use CSS:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD:  ol ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>

  1. first
  2. second
     a. sub
     b. under
  3. third
```

[image: Sample output]

To change the fullstops after the labels to something else see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5945161/4050592 for appropriate CSS.

Note that you can use the `#+ATTR_HTML` to add specific attributes to elements including a list.  This way you can make specific styling, such as:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD:  ol#al { list-style-type: upper-alpha; }
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>

#+ATTR_HTML: :id al
  1. first
  2. second
  3. third
```

[image: Styled sample]

Comment: Is it possible to have a more local change?  This would impact all the ol ol's around.

Comment: @Michaël You can use `<div>`s and have different css styles for different sections.

Comment: Would you mind indicating how to specify an ID in Org? Thanks!

Comment: @Michaël Example added

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much.